# A Question on Marketing Cloud Connector and AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

When using the Marketing Cloud Connector, can i use AMPScript to reference Contact Objects in Salesforce.com, where I'm targeting a Salesforce Campaign as the send list, or do the values need to exist in a data extension?

If possible, what do the AMPScript, or Personalization Strings look like to complete this?

Any answers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Answer (score 3):

When you use campaigns to send emails via the connector, marketing cloud imports the campaigns as a Data Extension (and is visible in Salesforce Data Extensions for days).

What this means is that for fields that are in the campaign you can reference them with personalization strings as you would do when you were sending via `Data Extensions`.

For example, if you have a `First Name`, you could access that field by entering

```
Dear %%First Name%%
```

To access difference objects (e.g. Contact / Lead) you would have to use the [RetrieveSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm) function.

```
%%[ var @rs
Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Id, FirstName,LastName', 'region', '=', 'west')
]%%
```

This will usuall return a rowset from which you would have to use the Field and Row function to narrow in on your fields.

**Reference**:

- [RetrieveSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrievesalesforceobjects.htm)
- [Row](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/row.htm)
- [Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/field.htm)
- [Field](https://ibb.co/dTCu2o)